# UIProgressView keep going thinner when reloading tableview

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I have table view loading data from URL. 
I create custom cell containing UIProgressView with below values :

```
let slider : UIProgressView = cell1.contentView.viewWithTag(13) as! UIProgressView
slider.transform = slider.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 0.5)
```

at first run it seem fine, and each time the app do `self.tblview.reloadData()`, UIProgressView getting thinner until disappear.

also, please see below screenshots : 
first time run 
[image]

after 5 times reloading of tableview 
[image]

Comment: You keep scaling it. Don't scale it more than once.

Comment: that's right ,, thanks @rmaddy